# Equilibrium change in the isotherms of real gasses

Tags: thermodynamics, thought-experiment

I am not sure I understand Isotherms of real gasses correctly (the equilibrium line to be specific):

[image: Isotherms of real gas]

Imagine a closed container with a piston between two compartments filled with a real gas (top blue line in the picture). The gasses can't mix but the ratio of the relative volume can be changed by moving the piston. Both gasses have the same temperature and the same volume.

Suppose the gasses are at the midpoint between **F** and **G**. If we move the separator we can change one compartment's gas to be at **F** and the other gas to be at **G**.

What happens if we do this? Are these true:

- The pressure on each side of the separator would be equal still. (So it wouldn't be pressed back into the original position)
- The gasses would still both be the same temperature which is the same as the starting temperature.
- If there is no friction and no kinetic energy is transferred from the movement of the piston to the particles then moving the piston doesn't really require any energy.

Comment: Are you talking about a fictitious model of a real gas, like the van der Waals equation, are you talking about an actual real gas, exhibiting a phase change between liquid and vapor?

Comment: An actual real gas. Yes the movement of the piston would cause the liquid vapour to change its quality. So there would be phase changes.

Comment: If you have both liquid and vapor, you are going to have to add or remove heat to move the piston, and one of the sections (or both) might contain both liquid and vapor.  Adding heat at constant total volume will also change the temperature, pressure, and quality.

Comment: In an actual experiment yes moving the piston will add heat to the section it is moving towards because of the particles colliding with it. But for the thought experiments sake we can suppose that we wait till the particles are all away from it and then move it.

Comment: No net work is done on the contents of the closed container.  You add heat, and the contents of the close container experience an increase in internal energy.